# Trying to parse GPX file in android studio using GPXparser library

Tags: android, android-studio, gpx

I have an gpx file that I have put in an assets folder under main.

I want to parse the gpx file and thus I have added gpxparser library.

this is my code in onCreate

```
    System.out.println("Before try");
    try {
        GPXParser p = new GPXParser();
        System.out.println("In the try");

      // InputStream in_s = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("gpx/timestamps_home_office_customer_hobby_home.gpx");

        InputStream in_s1 =   MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/timestamps_home_office_customer_hobby_home.gpx");


        GPX gpx = p.parseGPX(in_s1);

      System.out.println(gpx.getWaypoints()+"TESTING");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I get printed is null Testing in the log.

If i do gpx.getVersion(); I actually get 1.1 TESTING.

So it actually feels like i am reading from the gpx file.
What am i doing wrong, how can I print all of the waypoints for instance?